# Python 3.5 json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am receiving this error. I am using Python 3.5.0.
Here is my code:

```
import json
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm
import os.path

r = requests.get("http://prod.ivtr-od.tpg.ch/v1/GetStops.json?key=d95be980-0830-11e5-a039-0002a5d5c51b")
path = "/Users/me/Desktop/JSON/"
pbar = tqdm(r.json()["stops"])
for x in pbar:
    tree = {}
    fileMON = open(path + x["stopCode"] + ".json", "r", encoding='utf8')
    print(fileMON)
    if "MON" in json.loads(fileMON()):
        tree["MON"] = json.loads(fileMON())["MON"]
```

and this is the output :

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/Users/me/Desktop/JSON/31DCdeparts.json' mode='r' encoding='utf8'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json.py", line 14, in <module>
    tree["MON"] = json.loads(fileMON())["MON"]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

My JSON file is in the UTF8 encoding. Someone can help me ?

Comment: Couple questoins before I answer, to be sure I answer correctly. You have a file called /Users/me/Desktop/JSON/stopcode.json already? I ran this code, tried something similar and got a file not found error. Also, is tqdm necessary? I don't have it installed so I won't include that in an answer. I looked it up and I believe it cna be done without it, it just shows a load bar